# Why won't my implementation dependency resolve while my compile dependency will?

Tags: maven, gradle

When my dependency is configured as a compile dependency, gradle correctly resolves my artifact. However, when changing it to the more modern implementation dependency, resolution fails. Why might this be?

**As implementation**:

```
implementation "com.example.package:package-service:1.0.2"
```

This fails with the error:

```
Could not find com.example.package::
```

Note the missing name and version.

**As compile**:

```
compile "com.example.package:package-service:1.0.2"
```

Everything works.

Comment: which version of Gradle you are using?

Comment: Please add a full stacktrace, with the information provided, the only answer is: the error lies elsewhere.